# What concepts could I teach to children in a game about quantum-mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education

I think that games can also be used to teach things to young people or childs, different than for example a book and could be more "direct" than teaching them all the math background, I would like to hear about different concepts and way to teach them inside a game, the game could be a 3D game, or a puzzle game, or anything that you consider can be used as a tool for teach a **specific quantum-physics** concept.

And also would like to hear about games that have used for this specific purpose.

For example

[image: as a child I was doing paintings of particles and waves...]

as a child I was doing paintings of particles and waves but didn't get to quantum concepts I think we are missing something important in childs minds... Imagine, if we as a society make this happen??? as simples as possible for childs.

---

In my child mind I never reconciled one or the other, I always need to choose one or the other, but never liked because I left the other out (could not draw bot at same time)... later I finally learned to paint all yellow and good-bye particle-wave conflict... which now thinking was sad, because I was in the border of one of the most interesting things to discover as a simple child! and nobody cared to explain me why I was in conflict (not that teachers care about feelings of boys doing homework assigments or paintings, because childrens do homework not thinking and not even caring about particle-waves!!!).

It would be nice if we can help childs-minds reconcile things :).

---

I just found http://github.com/MITGameLab/OpenRelativity and sure the video http://youtube.com/watch?v=qol-zP9W5J4 or the PDF http://fdg2013.org/program/festival/openrelativity.pdf but this is relativity, not quantum things.

Comment: Have you made a newtonian-mechanics game first?

Comment: Yes and used newtonian physics in some engines.

Also see that I'm after child exposure to quantum mechanics.

Comment: I mean for example, when I was child, I liked to draw sun and some times I draw rays... and other times I dram like circles (for the expansion of the light)... and I thought little about how a straig line could cover the same than the circles... trust me when I say... that it would be nice to understand the difference (particles and waves... I was drawing... but I didn't get to quamtum physics as a 5-year old child)... Imagine, if we... as a society... make this happen??? as simples as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic here, and/or it may be too broad.

Comment: There is a game named quantum tick-tac-toe (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tic-tac-toe). Wikipedia: "The rules of quantum tic-tac-toe attempt to capture several phenomena of quantum systems: superposition, entanglement, collapse." I'd say the game rather succeeds in entanglement and collapse, but superposition is more like in a classical statistical ensemble (so the right name should rather be statistical tic-tac-toe).

Comment: Typo: "ear" --> "hear"

Comment: I would start with fully classical interference and other wave phenomena (I.e. you can cancel your oponent's move when using the same move with a different phase, but you might actually enhance his move at another place...). Then I would talk about specific experimental contexts in which things which we call particles behave as waves and after talking about atomic structure, picturing an atom as a standing electron wave around a center rather than the usual horrible planet-thing. But hard-core quantum mechanics about things being and non-being is not a good idea for small children.

Comment: Thanks for the examples and suggestions... as for "being and non-being is not a good idea for small children" I think that they are already exposed to far worse things on TV than the reality of quantum physics... also I don't think that it would be "being and non-being" but more like being and being.... like for example say:

You have 2 waves, each of them is independent and there you have places on a interference pattern for the same wave will show a peak or a cancellation, but the wave is still the wave (see more like "being being" 2 things at same time than "being and non-being")

Comment: I just found https://github.com/MITGameLab/OpenRelativity and sure the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qol-zP9W5J4  or the PDF http://www.fdg2013.org/program/festival/openrelativity.pdf but this is relativity, not quantum things.

Comment: As this question is currently being reviewed for being on topic, I'm reversing the bounty for now. In another couple days or so, feel free to start the bounty again.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to teach quantum theory concepts to kids, before they learned basic physics and probability theory with university level mathematics. Without these, any attempt to talk about quantum theory will inadvertently descend into confusing kids with misconceptions.

Comment: Kids have a lot of misconceptions (I can say one that at less half the childs and grown up people have... but I will enter in a debate over other issues), I think this whole "study first" is not really needed, I mean we already let childs see superman and things like that (that are more fantastic than real as quantum things).

If "we always protect childs" like for example "they will not understand grow up problems between mother and father" but they do and they will do best if informed.

I think we are missing this time where people can learn new lang, new concepts and communication skills.

Comment: At the end is only a game a visualization... like when you see a fantastic cartoon (not real thing). I mean I think in the future will be like programming, that will be taught at school from the start. And **remember childs are not only about 1-8** but also the teen until they get 18 and can be considered citizens one is still a child (doesn't matter if there are "in the middle names"). I don't think that there will be a problem if you start thinking of childs ages above 12 if you don't like the idea of childs below 12. At the end will they learn concepts like superman flies